# TypeORM @entity dynamic name based on connection name

Tags: connection, entity, typeorm

I'm trying to define only one entity for user table, but since I'm using multiple databases (with no connection when application starts), I need to provide a way to change @entity({name}) when connection is made (user tables have various names depending of database). Also, it would be great if there's a way to import entity upon connection, not earlier. Is it at least possible?

For entity I have smth like this:

```
function setEntityName(){
//how to pass connection name here? 
  return 'current_table_name';
}

@Entity({name:setEntityName()})
export class userSchema {
//...
```

And connection is initialized in another module like this:

```
const connection = await createConnection(connObj).then(connection => {
                    console.log("Connected to " + connObj.name);
                    return connection;
                }).catch(error => {console.log("TypeORM connection error: ", error); return false;});
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeORM MongoDB

I was also struggling with the same issue and here is my hack

Create an Entity same as your dynamic collection

```
@Entity()
export class Sample {
 ...
}
```

Add this entity to your connection.

```
const connection: Connection = await createConnection({
   ...
    entities: [Sample]
});
```

Use the Sample repository and change tableName before making a query

```
const repository = getRepository(Sample);
repository.metadata.tableName = "dynamic";

const data = await repository.find();
// returns result from the dynamic collection instead of sample
```

PS: I have only tested for a few operations like `find`, `findAndCount` and `insert`

Let me know if you found any other solution.

Comment: i'm not sure about find, findAndCount and insert, but for ```save``` i had to edit
``repository.metadata.tablePath = "dynamic";``